# SSRS: IIF statement to change fill color erroring out

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

In every example I could find to facilitate this, the logic is precisely what I'm using, but I can't get it to do what I need it to. It appears that I definitely can't use an AND condition inside the IIF expression, but even trying to account for that I don't get the correct results.

**Attempt #1:**

```
=iif(Fields!Days_to_Bill.Value >= 5, "Yellow", iif(Fields!Days_to_Bill.Value >= 10, "Red", "Transparent"))
```

This results in all numbers, including 10 and greater, being Yellow.
[image]

**Attempt 2:**

```
=iif(Fields!Days_to_Bill.Value >= 5 and < 10, "Yellow", iif(Fields!Days_to_Bill.Value >= 10, "Red", "Transparent"))
```

This results in the following error:

[image]

I really thought this was going to be a super simple expression, but I must be missing something.

Comment: On the second formula, you need to specify `Fields!Days_to_Bill.Value` again.... `=iif(Fields!Days_to_Bill.Value >= 5 and Fields!Days_to_Bill.Value < 10...`

Comment: You check if `Fields!Days_to_Bill.Value` has a value `>= 5` first, then `10`. The second `IIF` can therefore never be true, because the prior will be. Check for the higher value first, then the lower value.

Comment: Larnu, that also makes sense. Great point, thank you for chiming in.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, your second `IIF()` needs to repeat `Fields!Days_to_Bill.Value` for each condition you're checking.

So you need `=iif(Fields!Days_to_Bill.Value >= 5 and Fields!Days_to_Bill.Value < 10...`

Second, the first equation is correct and you are getting expected results. In an `IIF()` statement it will stop at the first 'True' value. Everything in your result set is >= 5, therefore they will all be yellow.

Comment: *Facepalm* Just like in a SQL query, you have to specify the column if you do an AND, even for the same column. Thank you so much, it didn't even occur to me to do this since I had a BETWEEN function in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the `and` if you simply change the order of your expression. Simply check for values that are >= 10 first. Also I made a guess at the desired highlighting logic, as I suspect you made some mistakes in your example.

```
=iif(Fields!Days_to_Bill.Value >= 10, "Transparent", iif(Fields!Days_to_Bill.Value >= 5 "Yellow", "Red"))
```